# Gatling: Exclude large response bodies from being logged

Tags: gatling

In the system we are testing with Gatling, the tested system hosts java script files that contain parts of the client program the real web browser would execute. I'm using .inferHtmlResources() option of HttpProtocolBuilder to pull those files from the server and .silentResources() option to not report them, since I'm just interested in causing system load like a real browser would cause.

If I want to see the requests and responses and set "io.gatling.http.engine.response" to level="TRACE", this causes logging of those resource java-script response bodies also. The problem is that they are over 60Mb in size, which causes heap out of memory errors.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
java.lang.StringUTF16.newBytesFor(StringUTF16.java:53)
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.inflate(AbstractStringBuilder.java:272)
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.putStringAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1718)
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.putStringAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1724)
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:583)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:179)
ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.FormattingConverter.write(FormattingConverter.java:39)
ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.writeLoopOnConverters(PatternLayoutBase.java:116)
ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout.doLayout(PatternLayout.java:176)
ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout.doLayout(PatternLayout.java:39)
ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder.encode(LayoutWrappingEncoder.java:114)
ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeOut(OutputStreamAppender.java:192)
ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.writeOut(FileAppender.java:281)
ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:228)
ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:272)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:259)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:426)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:386)
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.trace(Logger.java:430)
io.gatling.http.engine.response.StatsProcessor.logTx(StatsProcessor.scala:85)
io.gatling.http.engine.response.StatsProcessor.reportStats(StatsProcessor.scala:37)
io.gatling.http.engine.response.DefaultResponseProcessor.proceed(ResponseProcessor.scala:139)
io.gatling.http.engine.response.DefaultResponseProcessor.onComplete(ResponseProcessor.scala:123)
io.gatling.http.engine.GatlingHttpListener.onHttpResponseBodyChunk(GatlingHttpListener.scala:161)
io.gatling.http.client.impl.HttpAppHandler.channelRead(HttpAppHandler.java:202)
```

I can always fix that by increasing the Xmx memory size, but then if I run the test with multiple Gatling users, the log file is filled with those 60MB chunks of javascript content, which makes going through the log files pretty much impossible.

Is there a way to not log certain requests, or to limit the logging of request/reponse bodies to lets say first 100 bytes? I do want to see many of the other messages, but not these resource files.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to change a log level from `TRACE` to `DEBUG`.
`DEBUG` logs only failed requests. Logging everything is excessive, as it leads to issues such as you demonstrated.

Comment: This is how I normally run the performance tests. 
In certain situations when I debug the test suite because of problems, I need to log all the messages to get a better understanding of what does wrong. This is why it would be nice if I could alter or instruct the logging system to truncate the huge messages bodies of these resource request responses. Now a single big response can break the test execution with an exception in not so civilized manner. If there was an option something like .maxLoggedBodyLength()